# how to create a spinner with radio buttons

Tags: android, spinner

In main.xml I would like to have a spinner1 with two radio buttons and a spinner2 with 3 checkboxes. I don't know how to define and create this spinners in Main.java.
Need some help.

**main.xml**

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Spinner
android:id="@id/spinner2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

spinner1 - needs to have radio buttons and spinner2 need to have multiple checkboxes

```
main.java

privare Spinner spiner1,spiner2;
public void OnCreate(BUndle SaveInstaceState)
{
super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main)

spiner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

//what to do from here?

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a strings.xml file in res/values/ and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
<string name="spinnerstr">Choose an item</string>
<string-array name="spinner_array">
    <item>apple</item>
    <item>orange</item>
    <item>grapes</item>
</string-array>
```

In your spinner.java, add the followoing:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

**Accepted answer doesn't work anymore.**

Instead use this to have the radio button look:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
```

And for those who are using custom layouts, just add `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` which makes the radio button align with the text.